# How do I diff two text files in Windows Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell

I have two text files and want to find the differences between them using Windows Powershell. Is there something similar to the Unix diff tool available? Or is there another other way I haven't considered?

I've tried `compare-object`, but got this cryptic output:

```
PS C:\> compare-object one.txt two.txt

InputObject                                                 SideIndicator
-----------                                                 -------------
two.txt                                                     =>
one.txt                                                     <=
```

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Figured it out myself. Because Powershell works with .net objects rather than text, you need to use get-content to expose the contents of the text files. So to perform what I was trying to do in the question, use:

```
compare-object (get-content one.txt) (get-content two.txt)
```

Comment: I was very surprised when I tried to compare two files: an unsorted array of numbers, and the same array of numbers after sorting them. There is no output despite the files being very different. Apparently, compare-object doesn't consider order.

Comment: @cgmb - You can use `-SyncWindow 0` to fix that, I believe, though I'm unsure if it's only recently been introduced. It's not particularly smart about it, though.

Comment: Note that this is terribly slow when comparing big files. DOS' `fc.exe` or *nix' `diff` are better options there.

Comment: @cgmb can't reproduce with files `1 2 3`, `3 2 1`. What was your example?

Answer (score 73):

A simpler way of doing it is to write:

```
diff (cat file1) (cat file2)
```

Comment: Diff and cat are just aliases for Compare-Object and Get-Content in PowerShell. It is the same thing.

Comment: despite this being the same as the accepted answer, I like using this syntax more

Comment: Note that it doesn't behave like *nix `diff` at all, as other answers here note. And when I used a more complex expression in place of `cat` I got incorrect output, so I'll join the others in the recommendation to avoid doing this  in PowerShell if you come from *nix.

Answer (score 47):

Or you could use the DOS `fc` command like so (This shows the output of both files so you will have to scan for the differences):

```
fc.exe filea.txt fileb.txt > diff.txt
```

**`fc` is an alias for the Format-Custom cmdlet so be sure to enter the command as `fc.exe`**.  Please note that many DOS utilities don't handle UTF-8 encoding.

You can also spawn a CMD process and run `fc` within it.

```
start cmd "/c  ""fc filea.txt fileb.txt >diff.txt"""
```

This instructs PowerShell to start a process with the 'cmd' program using the parameters in quotes.  In the quotes, is the '/c' cmd option to run the command and terminate.  The actual command to run by cmd in the process is `fc filea.txt fileb.txt` redirecting the output to the file `diff.txt`.

You can use the DOS `fc.exe` from within powershell.

Comment: +1 for bring out the DOS ^_^

Comment: "fc" was not working for me, and I didn't realize I had to specify it as "fc.exe" to differentiate it from Format-Custom. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I'm a complete philistine, but this seems much more useable to me.  It solved my problem very nicely.

Comment: The only problem is it HATES unicode.

Answer (score 9):

diff on *nix is not part of the shell, but a separate application.

Is there any reason you can't just use diff.exe under PowerShell?

You can download a version from the UnxUtils package (http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Because PowerShell is included now, nothing to download and install.

Comment: I just ended up using `git diff`, because I already had it installed. Neither `fc.exe` nor `Compare-Object` produced the output I expected.

Comment: I rather not download essential utilities from a developer that not only uses an ambiguous date format but also switches between different formats in the same list (What is new: 10/28/00... 27-06-03...). Microsoft may love Linux but not it's core utilities...

Answer (score 8):

compare-object (aka diff alias) is pathetic if you expect it to behave something like a unix diff. I tried the diff (gc file1) (gc file2), and if a line is too long, I can't see the actual diff and more importantly, I can't tell which line number the diff is on.

When I try adding -passthru, I now can see the difference, but I lose which file the difference is in, and I still don't get a line number.

My advice, don't use powershell to find differences in files.  As someone else noted, fc works, and works a little better than compare-object, and even better is downloading and using real tools like the unix emulator that Mikeage mentioned.

Comment: It also appears to do a set comparison (i.e. ignoring the order) as `-SyncWindow` is maxint by default. Setting that to 0 doesn't make it work like `diff` either... And when I passed a pipe `(... | select-object ...)` as input, it just printed nonsense, so I gave up.

Comment: Compare-Object isn't pathetic, it's intended to "compares two sets of objects" (see `Get-Help Compare-Object | more`). Not what you're trying to do. Regarding the cut-off output, PowerShell commands return objects that can be scripted/piped without parsing. If you're interested in text output, check out the `Format-*` cmdlets or pipe to your favorite editor and get the line numbers you want.

Answer (score 6):

`fc.exe` is better for text comparing since it designed to work like *nix diff, i.e. compares lines sequentially, showing the actual differences and trying to re-synchronise (if the differing sections have different lengths). It also has some useful control options (text/binary, case sensitivity, line numbers, resynchronisation length, mismatch buffer size) and provides exit status (-1 bad syntax, 0 files same, 1 files differ, 2 file missing). Being a (very) old DOS utility, it does have a few limitations. Most notably, it does not automatically work with Unicode, treating the 0 MSB of ASCII characters as a line terminator so the file becomes a sequence of 1 character lines (@kennycoc: use the /U option to specify BOTH files are Unicode, WinXP onwards) and it also has a hard line buffer size of 128 characters (128 bytes ASCII, 256 bytes Unicode) so long lines get split up and compared separately.

compare-object is designed to determine if 2 objects are member-wise identical. if the objects are collections then they are treated as SETS (see help compare-object), i.e. UNORDERED collections without duplicates. 2 sets are equal if they have the same member items irrespective of order or duplications. This severely limits its usefulness for comparing text files for differences. Firstly, the default behaviour collects the differences until the entire object (file = array of strings) has been checked thus losing the information regarding the position of the differences and obscuring which differences are paired (and there is no concept of line number for a SET of strings). Using -synchwindow 0 will cause the differences to be emitted as they occur but stops it from trying to re-synchronise so if one file has an extra line then subsequent line comparisons can fail even though the files are otherwise identical (until there is a compensatory extra line in the other file thereby realigning the matching lines). However, powershell is extremely versatile and a useful file compare can be done by utilising this functionality, albeit at the cost of substantial complexity and with some restrictions upon the content of the files. If you need to compare text files with long (> 127 character) lines and where the lines mostly match 1:1 (some changes in lines between files but no duplications within a file such as a text listing of database records having a key field) then by adding information to each line indicating in which file it is, its position within that file and then ignoring the added information during comparison (but including it in the output) you can get a *nix diff like output as follows (alias abbreviations used):

```
diff (gc file1 | % -begin { $ln1=0 } -process { '{0,6}<<:{1}' -f ++$ln1,$_ }) (gc file2 | % -begin { $ln2=0 } -process { '{0,6}>>:{1}' -f ++$ln2,$_ }) -property { $_.substring(9) } -passthru | sort | out-string -width xx
```

where xx is the length of the longest line + 9

#### Explanation

- `(gc file | % -begin { $ln=0 } -process { '{0,6}<<:{1}' -f ++$ln,$_ })` gets the content of the file and prepends the line number and file indicator (<< or >>) to each line  (using the format string operator) before passing it to diff.
- `-property { $_.substring(9) }` tells diff to compare each pair of objects (strings) ignoring the first 9 characters (which are the line number and file indicator). This utilises the ability to specify a calculated property (the value of a script block) instead of the name of a property.
- `-passthru` causes diff to output the differing input objects (which include the line number and file indicator) instead of the differing compared objects (which don't).
- `sort-object` then puts all the lines back into sequence.
  out-string stops the default truncation of the output to fit the screen width (as noted by Marc Towersap) by specifying a width big enough to avoid truncation. Normally, this output would be put into a file which is then viewed using a scrolling editor (e.g. notepad).

#### Note

The line number format {0,6} gives a right justified, space padded 6 character line number (for sorting). If the files have more than 999,999 lines then simply change the format to be wider. This also requires altering the `$_.substring` parameter (3 more than the line number width) and the out-string xx value (maximum line length + `$_.substring` parameter).

Comment: The long solution given by Mr Shunz is elegantly designed for a nice readable output. Nonetheless, it has got an inherent issue: It does not return line movements (such as a couple of swapped lines). For example, if file 1 contains lines 1, 2 and 3, and file 2 contains lines 1, 3 and 2, no differences will be reported.

Answer (score 4):

[WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) is another good GUI-based diff tool.

Comment: This is how I did it in the past, which is a manual process, that I wanted to replace with a small script.

Answer (score 3):

As others have noted, if you were expecting a unix-y diff output, using the powershell diff alias would let you down hard. For one thing, you have to hold it's hand in actually reading files (with gc / get-content). For another, the difference indicator is on the right, far from the content -- it's a readability nightmare.

The solution for anyone looking for a sane output is

1. get a real diff (eg from GnuWin32)
2. edit %USERPROFILE%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
3. add the line

   ```
   remove-item alias:diff -force
   ```

The -force argument is required because Powershell is quite precious about this particular inbuilt alias. If anyone is interested, having GnuWin32 installed, I also include the following in my powershell profile:

```
remove-item alias:rm
remove-item alias:mv
remove-item alias:cp
```

Mainly because Powershell doesn't understand arguments which are run together and typing, for example "rm -Force -Recurse" is a lot more effort than "rm -rf".

Powershell has some nice features, but there are some things it should just not try to do for me.

Answer (score 1):

There's also [Windiff](http://www.grigsoft.com/download-windiff.htm) which provides a GUI diff interface (great for use with GUI based CVS/SVN programs)

Comment: But the question was specifically : How do I diff two text files **in Windows Powershell**

Answer (score 1):

This is the first question that comes up if you search for file diff in Powershell.

If you don't necessarily care what is different about the files and just want to know if they are different then I find that using Get-FileHash on each file and then comparing the two hashes is the most efficient way to do this. It's mostly useful when you have to compare a lot of files between two locations for differences.

Something like the below where the variables are the full names of the two files to compare.

```
function FilesAreDifferent($f1,$f2)
{
    return (Get-FileHash $f1).hash  -ne (Get-FileHash $f2).hash
}
```